# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, graphql, expo

I use https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/ for fetching data from GraphQL server in React Native.

The component is implemented as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import { View, Text } from "react-native"
import { HashtagsProps } from "./types"
import { useQuery } from "urql";

const HashtagsQuery = `
query {
    searchHashtags(input: {pattern: "vegan"}) {
      id
      name
    }
}  
`

export default function Hashtags({ navigation }: HashtagsProps) {

    const [result] = useQuery({
        query: HashtagsQuery
    })

    const { data, fetching, error } = result;

    if (fetching) console.log("loading");
    if (error) console.log(error.message);
    console.log(data)

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hashtags</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

When running the app, the query works as expected and I receive data from GraphQL server.

However, the console shows error messages:

> Unhandled promise rejection, [RangeError: Maximum call stack size
> exceeded.] at
> node_modules/core-js/internals/host-report-errors.js:5:32 in
> module.exports at
> http://192.168.178.27:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:205269:138
> in dispatchEvent at node_modules/core-js/modules/es.promise.js:163:23
> in perform$argument_0 at
> node_modules/core-js/internals/perform.js:3:20 in module.exports at
> node_modules/core-js/modules/es.promise.js:160:22 in
> task.call$argument_1

I use **expo** version **^42.0.0**.

I also tried to omit graphql query as follows:

```
export default function Hashtags({ navigation }: HashtagsProps) {

   
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hashtags</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

and the error messages do not appear anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query will try to call every time.
Can you please wrap with useEffect for once call?
then if you have update you can add it useEffect deps.